# parse json array in android

Tags: java, android, json

I need a help... I have a php file which returns me two json Arrays which are as       follows:

```
[{ "id":"1",
   "item":"hammers",
   "aisle":"20"
 }
 { "id":"1",
   "item":"hammers",
   "aisle":"20"
 }]

[{ "id":"1",
   "itemFound":"Your item #item",
   "ThankYou":"and Thank You for using Txtcore!"
 }]
```

Now, I want to get the second array items in Android. I have the following code now which is like :
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

```
         for (int   i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);       
            items.add(jsonObject.getString("item"));
            aisles.add(""+jsonObject.getString("item");

         }
```

But obviously, that returns me the objects from the first array. I want to get the Objects from the second array. Any suggestions.

Comment: is it the full JSON data?

Comment: yes, the top coding is the json data sent by the php file.

Comment: I just want to get the second array object values in java/android.

Comment: is this really your JSON? it isnt valid

Comment: @user3485703: I don't think it should be the complete json data.Do check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid but u can get your element as follows. It is a solution from many(just a worlaround).

```
String str = "YOUR_JSON_RESPONSE";
String array[] = str.split("\\[\\{");// 
try {
     JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray("[{" + array[2]));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to do some dirty coding because the data return by the PHP page is not well formed JSON.
You could try to transform the JSON data to:
    `{ "data" : [ <array_1>, <array_2> ]}` And then use the JSON parser. A simple replacement with a regexp could be fine.

```
  result.replaceAll("\\]\\s*\\[", "], [");
  StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer(result);
  buffer.insert(0,"{ \"data\": ");
  buffer.append(" }");
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
  JSONArray secondArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONArray(1);
```

The creation of a valid JSON string can be done in one step with the appropriate regexp. Hope some one with more time can post it here.